# TTR and Quantmod Package of R

Tags: r, quantmod

How to resolve the situation when different companies, listed on different stock exchanges, have the same symbol code. For example, I want Pakistan State Oil (PSO) stock prices. The company is listed in Pakistan Stock exchange (PSX), however, I am not able to get the correct price quote for this company.

Comment: There are ways to solve the problem when the same symbol is used on different exchanges for different companies.  But `getSymbols` does not have a method to get data for any companies on KSE.  So you need to find another data provider.

Comment: Dear Joshua, Thanks a lot for prompt response. Can you please suggest some other data providers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot.  I do not know of any.